# webcam access using opencv with processing in an applet or application

Tags: opencv, applet, processing, signed-applet

I made a small sketch with processing using opencv to face detect and track. But when I export as an application and start it nothing happens, same as an applet. First I exported the applet and thought this must be a security issue, and struggled with some hack for processing to sign your java applet.

http://processing.org/hacks/hacks:signapplet

With no luck I thought I would atleast be able to run it as an application but no success.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: [JavaCV does run in applets](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/HowToMakeAnApplet), and I'm sure it would me no trouble with Processing

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OSX 10.6 there is a known bug with the quicktime camera stuff not working in 64-bit mode. Make sure both your install of processing and the exported application are set to run in 32-bit mode.

Right click -> get info -> Open in 32-bit mode